# send email with swiftmailer external smtp option without waiting the end of the sending procedure

Tags: yii2, swiftmailer

i'm building a web app with Yii2 Framework. I send an email when I add some data to the database, so I use the default swift mailer class.
The external smtp option seems to be significatively slower than phpmailer, but I can't use the latter for security issue so I'm forced to use an smtp external server.

I wonder if there is a way to send email with external smtp in background without waiting the end of the send procedure for my script to go on.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Following this guide will get you what you need for yii2.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-events.html

With swiftmailer we trigger a postexecute event which wait until the end of the execution of code to run. We use symfony2 but yii2 as from the guide have the same logic.